# How to calculate relative time spans using Java (code converting problem)?

Tags: java, datetime, relative-time-span

I decided to give myself a challenge on Java that implements [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/calculate-relative-time-in-c-sharp) achievement.

The things I have to do is get `LocalDateTime`, convert the same code from the linked question's answers, then receiving a string from the function.

Here's what I've done so far:

```java
public static String relTime(LocalDateTime now)
{
    // accepted answer converted to Java
    const int min = 60 * SECOND;
    const int hour = 60 * MINUTE;
    const int day = 24 * HOUR;
    const int mon = 30 * DAY;
    
    // still don't know how to convert this method
    var ts = new TimeSpan(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - yourDate.Ticks);
    double delta = Math.Abs(ts.TotalSeconds);
    
    if (delta < 1 * MINUTE)
        return ts.Seconds == 1 ? "one second ago" : ts.Seconds + " seconds ago";

    if (delta < 2 * MINUTE)
        return "a minute ago";
    
    if (delta < 45 * MINUTE)
        return ts.Minutes + " minutes ago";
    
    if (delta < 90 * MINUTE)
        return "an hour ago";
    
    if (delta < 24 * HOUR)
        return ts.Hours + " hours ago";

    if (delta < 48 * HOUR)
        return "yesterday";
    
    if (delta < 30 * DAY)
        return ts.Days + " days ago";
    
    if (delta < 12 * MONTH)
    {
        int months = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((double)ts.Days / 30));
        return months <= 1 ? "one month ago" : months + " months ago";
    }
    else
    {
        int years = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((double)ts.Days / 365));
        return years <= 1 ? "one year ago" : years + " years ago";
    }
}
```

The only problem that I should encounter is from `var ts = new TimeSpan(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - yourDate.Ticks);`.

Although I read 2 questions from Stack Overflow finding equivalents of `TimeSpan` and `Ticks`, I baely have any ideas how to properly convert the line of code. Also, I have to get a `double` which will need `math.abs()` to get `TotalSeconds` which I can't really find a proper way to deal with either, but I did find [`ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds`](https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/java.time.ZoneOffset/totalSeconds) and still don't know how to deal with it.

So how can I convert this properly?

```cs
var ts = new TimeSpan(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - yourDate.Ticks);
double delta = Math.Abs(ts.TotalSeconds);
```

Comment: Perhaps classes [Period and/or Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html) are appropriate?

Comment: @Abra I read a Stack Overflow question on that. The parameters is what I don't fully understand about them.

Comment: @Abra Finally understood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to gain a deeper understanding of what this method actually does. Literally translating code from C# to Java won't give you a good solution and gets you stuck on language-specific details.

The two lines basically calculate the (absolute) difference in seconds of a `timestamp` to the current time. This can be written in Java as follows:

```
Duration duration = Duration.between(LocalDateTime.now(), timestamp);
long delta = duration.abs().getSeconds();
```

*I'm just addressing your actual question here on how to transform these two lines. The provided snippet is not valid Java code and some parts are missing. `delta` is the difference in seconds which does not necessarily need to be a double. The argument you pass to your method should be named anything else than `now` because this is the timestamp you want to compare to the current time inside the method.*

Answer (score 1):

You could use SimpleDateFormat to create a nice display format (use something like `"HH hours, mm minutes and ss seconds ago"` for the format (not sure if this exact example works)). You could also use Instant to get the current time, and you can use `Instant.now().minusSeconds(Instant.now().minusSeconds(seconds).getEpochSeconds())` for the time difference (or just use System.currentTimeMillis() and multiply by 1000).

Alternatively, you could use Duration and write a custom display format using getSeconds() and getHours() etc.

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.